# 91 errors on a single .aspx page with no trace to any of them

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I appear to be having an issue. I'm using WebForms with Visual Studio 2012 and currently, on my default.aspx file there are 91 errors, with no actual way to trace them back to the source. All that the file contains is this code (which, by the way, works flawlessly).

```
<% 
if (App.Context.Site.MenuItems.Any()) 
{
  Response.Redirect(App.Context.Site.MenuItems.First().Page.Url);
}
else 
{ 
  Response.Write("<h2>This website has no menu items.</h2>");
  Response.End();
}  
%>
```

[image: The picture]

I have tried cleaning/rebuilding it, even creating a new default file for that, it seems to always be the same.

Any clue, anyone?

Comment: The image you tried to add is missing. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Syntax error, 'Namespace' statement must end with a matching 'End Namespace', End of statement expected, Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda, Declaration expected, 'Static' is not valid on a member variable declaration, Keyword is not valid as an identifier and a few more - repeating themselves one after another, without a line provided

Comment: do you have a designer file along with your aspx file. if not then right click your aspx file and select convert to web application, and rebuild the solution. See if this works.

Comment: " 'Namespace' statement must end with a matching 'End Namespace' " - this is VB.NET syntax, there is no 'End Namespace' in C# - which is what your code is. What is the 'Language' attribute of your Page declaration ?